# orientjs install issues both on windows and ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, npm, orientdb, orientjs

I installed orientjs with npm on windows and ubuntu.

When I execute the file that requires orientjs, it gives node-gyp rebuild error on windows and can not find module 'arrify' on ubuntu.

On Windows
I tried hundreds of times with binding.gyp and binding.cc files.
I also tried npm install --global --production windows-build-tools, but it didn't work.

On Ubuntu
When I install 'arrify', it gives another error of 'parse-function'.

Could you help me fix these?

These are the error image of ubuntu and windows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xvKD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FexjD.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the parse-function package that causes this issue. The OrientJS team fixed it by hard-coding the version of parse-function. Should be resolved per: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs/pull/416/commits/0ab736b351e89374bbc1c0bafbd71b567ccdd8bd